# How to match new lines in awk?

Tags: awk

Input file `text.txt:`

```
foo()
{
}

buz()
{
}
```

Awk `script.awk`:

```
BEGIN {
    RS = "\n\n+";
    FS = "\n";
}
/[a-z]+\(\)\n/ {print "FUNCTION: " $1;}
{print "NOT FOUND: " $0;}
```

Running script:

> awk -f script.awk text.txt

gives:

```
NOT FOUND: foo()
{
}
NOT FOUND: buz()
{
}
```

But I've expected to match both functions WITH newlines. How to do this?

Comment: What version of awk are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
BEGIN {
    RS = "";
    FS = "\n";
}
/[a-z]+\(\)/ {print "FUNCTION: " $1;}
!/[a-z]+\(\)/ {print "NOT FOUND: " $0;}
```

If you want to verify that there is nothing after the () you can do this:

$1~/[a-z]+()$/ {print "FUNCTION: " $1;}

I don't know why newline isn't matched. Maybe someone would explain it.

Comment: I've read than `RS = ""` and `RS = "\n\n+"` are the same, but they are not as you've mentioned above. But why..

Answer (score 5):

Since you're already using "\n" as the FS, you can just do matching against $1:

```
awk -v RS='\n\n+' -v FS='\n' '
  $1 ~ /^[a-z]+\(\)$/ {print "FUNCTION: " $1; next}
  {print "NOT FOUND: " $0}
' text.txt
```

This worked with gawk:

```
FUNCTION: foo()
FUNCTION: buz()
```

Comment: I need to match the expressions _with_ new line `\n`. In your example there is no `\n` at the end of regexp.

Comment: You're using newline as your field separator. Why don't you want to take advantage of that?

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU awk):

```
awk '{if(/^[a-z]+\(\)\n/)print "FUNCTION:"$1; else print "NOT FOUND: "$0}' RS="" file
```

Comment: I need to match the expressions _with_ new line `\n`. In your example there is no `\n` at the end of regexp.

Comment: Oops! forgot the newline! Solution amended.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what output you expect excactly.

In order to process FS in awk you need to indroduce a dummy command like $1=$1. Without it no filed parsing is done.

So if you expect result like this:

```
foo() { }
buz() { }
```

Just type:

```
awk  '{$1=$1; print} '  RS='\n\n' FS='\n' OFS=" "
```

Comment: RS="" is enough than RS='\n\n'